# Struts2 DependencyException when upgrading from 2.5.29 to 2.5.33 - missing JAR dependency?

Tags: dependency-injection, struts2, runtime-error, upgrade, struts-config

I'm working on bringing a Struts2 application up to date because of a reported security issue. Currently it's using 2.5.29 and it needs to use the latest, 2.5.33. This is an older application using Ant for building, so I'm having to figure out all the dependent JARs *by hand*. However, whenever I try to hit the application I get an internal 500 error with a pretty huge stack trace. I've included here just the part of the stack trace that I think is relevant:

```
Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=com.opensymphony.xwork2.security.NotExcludedAcceptedPatternsChecker, name='default'] in public void org.apache.struts2.components.Component.setNotExcludedAcceptedPatterns(com.opensymphony.xwork2.security.NotExcludedAcceptedPatternsChecker).
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMembers(ContainerImpl.java:140) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMethods(ContainerImpl.java:111) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:89) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:85) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:85) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:70) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:66) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:155) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:79) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.get(ReferenceCache.java:123) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:466) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:505) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:503) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:558) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:503) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:48) ~[struts2-core-2.5.33.jar:2.5.33]
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout.sftaLayoutNoTitle_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fhead_005f0(xLayoutNoTitle_jsp.java:423) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout.sftaLayoutNoTitle_jsp._jspService(xLayoutNoTitle_jsp.java:192) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.84]
```

Digging into the JSP that seems to be having the problem, the error seems to happen at the point where it hits a `<s:head />` tag in that JSP. I've checked all the dependent JARs but I'm not seeing the problem at all and I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this. My thinking at the moment is that either I have a too-old version of one of the dependencies, or I've completely missed a dependency. The JARs I have at the moment include these:

- struts2-core-2.5.33.jar
- struts2-spring-plugin-2.5.33.jar
- struts2-tiles-plugin-2.5.33.jar
- tiles-api-3.0.8.jar
- tiles-autotag-core-runtime-1.2.jar
- tiles-core-3.0.8.jar
- tiles-el-3.0.8.jar
- tiles-freemarker-3.0.8.jar
- tiles-jsp-3.0.8.jar
- tiles-ognl-3.0.8.jar
- tiles-request-api-1.0.7.jar
- tiles-request-freemarker-1.0.7.jar
- tiles-request-jsp-1.0.7.jar
- tiles-request-servlet-1.0.7.jar
- tiles-servlet-3.0.8.jar
- tiles-template-3.0.8.jar

Incidentally, as a test I tried using 2.5.30 (i.e. one step up from the original 2.5.29) and the problem happens there too; it seems the problem is being caused by something that happened at that release and not specifically something in 2.5.33.

The Struts configuration for the initial URL I'm hitting has no Action method - it just goes directly to a Tiles definition that renders the JSP. With 2.5.29, it works fine. With 2.5.30 and up, 500 error. I've been on this for something like six hours and I'm stumped.

Comment: As Roman says--managing transitive dependencies by had is tedious and error-prone--a surefire way to self-sabotage. Take a step back, set up the project correctly, let a tool handle trans. deps. (e.g., Maven, Gradle, ...), and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with interface [`NotExcludedAcceptedPatternsChecker`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.5.30/com/opensymphony/xwork2/security/NotExcludedAcceptedPatternsChecker.html). It is missed to initialize by Struts container from the configuration contained in `struts2-core-2.5.3x`. Since you managing dependencies *by hand*, it's error-prone approach. The beans are configured in the `struts-default.xml` which is included in the `struts2-core-2.5.3x.jar`. You are right that the new interface and implementation classes appeared from Struts 2.5.30. But your application somehow using old configuration file probably from the same jar with a different version. Looks like both jars are found on the classpath while your application is deployed.

Comment: This answer was instrumental in finding the root problem. It turns out, the original developer apparently didn't properly understand Struts and had copied the "struts-default.xml" from an older version of Struts directly into WEB-INF/classes. This file is read during deployment (it's referenced in the Struts Filter initialization parameters) and contains old beans definitions including some classes that no longer exist. Removing the copy so it would read the one from the Struts JAR appears to have solved the problem. I wouldn't have found this without the pointer from @romanc - THANK YOU!